# Fixing brackets indentation. New line indentation off by one space or tab

Tags: indentation, brackets, emmet

See image:
http://www.criweb.com.br/jd/emmet.gif

To reproduce

Take any document.

Create an element with one or more children.

Set cursor at the end of parent element.

Press [enter] to create a new line.

See how the indentation is short exactly one space (or tab).

Have any configuration to fix this problem?